# How can i make this change on C function struct?

Tags: c, function, struct, macros

I've been trying to emulate Python instance construction on C, but i cant find a way to get the struct name backwards to the function and give it as parameter

```
typedef struct queue {
    .
    .
    ssize_t (*add)(struct queue *, int);
} queue;

ssize_t add(queue *self, int value)
{
    /* Add a element to the queue */
}

int main(void)
{
    queue *clients = createQueue(5); /* Here i create the queue struct */

    clients.add(5); /* I want to convert this instruction to "clients.add(&clients, 5);" */
}
```

I've triyed to use macros but I've found i can't use regex or something like that

Comment: This is simply a thing you don't do in C. If you have a need for such things, use C++

Comment: Python is an object language, C is not, but C++ is

Comment: Ok, i thought it was simple because it's just a replace, now I've to declare struct address on every method manually, thanks anyway

Comment: C isn't Python. If you try to make it look and act like Python you'll either make huge mess with macros or go mad and write a new programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to 'emulate' an object language in a non object language like C, but simple to do in C++ like :

```
struct queue { // a 'struct' is a 'class' where all is 'public' by default
    .
    .
    ssize_t add(int); // in C++ 'this' corresponding to 'self' does not have to be explicitly placed in the params list
};

ssize_t queue::add(int value)
{
    /* Add a element to the queue */
    return ...a ssize_t...;
}

int main(void)
{
    queue * clients = createQueue(5); /* Here i create the queue struct */

    clients->add(5); // '->' rather than '.' because clients is a 'queue*' rather than a 'queue'
}
```

The corresponding of Python 'self' is named 'this' in C++ and you do not not have to place it explicitly in the parameter list, it is implicit.

Note in C++ there is no garbage collector like in Python, probably `createQueue` allocate the queue in the heap, in that case if you want to liberate the allocated memory before the end of the execution you have to do `delete queue;`

And to finish there is an implicit `return 0;` at the end of *main* if you do not return by yourself